# Task.Factory doesn't release memory?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, windows-services, taskfactory

I use a Timer this way:

```
t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 10000;
t.Elapsed += ElapsedEvent;
```

and that's the ElapsedEvent method:

```
private void ElapsedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    t.Stop();

    try
    {
        var sessions = GetActiveSessions();

        foreach (var session in sessions)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyProcessTask(session));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    
    t.Start();
}
```

i.e. it will be executed every 10000ms.

But the memory in RAM is increasing, ever, and I need to restart the Windows Service (where this code is executed).

Is the way I use Task.Factory incorrect? Does the memory allocated by thread never be released by Garbage collector this way?

Comment: Do you need `MyProcessTask(session)` to run in the background? It will continue to run after the timer and the garbage collector then may not clean up the resources for these tasks. You could also be creating a lot of tasks and not giving the garbage collector a chance depending on how many active sessions there are. What is the ultimate aim here?

Comment: Also an important note here is that `System.Timers.Timer` will create a new thread each time for `ElapsedEvent` while `System.Threading.Timer` will re(use) a `ThreadPool` thread. Try using `System.Threading.Timer` instead and observe if it fixes the memory leak. If not, we can then take a look at the overarching goal.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'm using System.Timers.Timer in fact. And yes: I need to run in background (MyProcessTask could take some times to end, so every time the process must run with independence).

Comment: "the garbage collector then may not clean up the resources for these tasks" why? How can I make sure all items will be removed once "released"?

Comment: So yes, try using `System.Threading.Timer` instead and see what impact that has on your performance. Re garbage collection, `StartNew` essentially queues the task to be added to the thread pool to then be executed by a worker thread. The worker thread that executes the task is not created or managed by the task itself, but rather by the thread pool i.e. task finishes but memory by that thread is not automatically released as the thread pool is managing it. Because the thread pool wants to be efficient and essentially 'reuse' it.

Comment: The memory used by a worker thread will be released when the worker thread is no longer needed by the thread pool. This can happen when the application is stopped or when the thread pool is closed. However, if you have long running tasks that are still running on those threads, you're essentially going to exhaust the thread pool and resources.

Comment: What I would advise typically is to use separate threads to execute your long-running tasks, rather than relying on the thread pool. To ensure that the memory used by a worker thread is released when the task it is executing completes, you can use a separate thread that is created and managed by the task, rather than using a worker thread from the thread pool. You could try passing `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to your `Task.Factory.StartNew` method and see if that helps. Profiling is key here but try the above two suggestions (separately and then together) and see if it's better or worse